# Is it possible to install only the required LaTeX tool "pdflatex" in Ubuntu?

Tags: pdftex, installing, texlive

I do not know the dependencies b/w the tools provided by the LaTeX bulky lib. A suggested command to install LaTeX tools on Ubuntu is:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

It's full installation requires almost 1,801 MB of disk-space. What I need is only the `pdflatex` command line tool. Is it possible to install the required tool(s) only? If not what is the best way to install the required libs/tools?

Comment: No. You will need also at least some base packages. You can install texlive-core + packages you need.

Comment: @Eddy_Em thanks for your comments, should I assume that there not optimal way to install it ?

Comment: Every distro have its own package manager. And maintainers of distro have their own point of view onto package building. So, for example, in archlinux texlive is split onto many small packages. In debian, I think, it must be alike. The smallest working set of latex is almost 300 megabytes. For example, my installation is near 0.5GB. The only optimal way is to install texlive-core and after that - some packages you need (you will now that they aren't installed in your system by latex error messages).

Comment: thanks @Eddy_Em, I think texlive-core is better than full one

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Almost every distro have its own package manager. Maintainers of any distro have their own point of view onto package building: its dependencies and its contents. 
So, for example, in Archlinux `TeXLive` is split onto many small packages. In Debian and Ubuntu, I think, it must be alike.

The smallest working set of `LaTeX` have volume about 300 megabytes. For example, my installation of `TeXLive` is near 0.5GB. The only optimal way is to `install texlive-core` and after that - some packages you need (you will know that they aren't installed in your system by latex error messages).

For example, package `texlive-bin` contains all binary files, but no style files; `texlive-core` contains main style files and some auxiliary utils. For using `bibtex` with different bibliography styles, you will need `texlive-bibtex-extra`. `texlive-langcyrillic` contains support of Cyrillic languages. For using different styles to include images into your file you will need `texlive-pictures`. Et cetera.

Answer (score 45):

On Ubuntu 12.04:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-base
```

Seems to have got the job done in 175MB.

Comment: @Angus Carr, fair enough thanks. I assume debian Wheezy will also  support that ?

Comment: It was only 91.9MB on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS. I spun up an EC2 box to compile my resume. It was worth the pennies. ;-)

Comment: 92 mb downloaded, 226 mb used on disk with ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 8):

Because I rarely needed to use LaTeX, I used to use EC2 for compiling my documents. I liked that I could throw everything away when I was done, but the setup was time consuming. I found a better way.

Docker is a great tool for this because you don't have to make any changes to your main system. Here is a way to use [a Docker image I created](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/richardbronosky/latex-compiler/).

```
docker run -i richardbronosky/latex-compiler < document.tex > document.pdf
```

If you need supplementary files you can pipe in an uncompressed tar and it will be detected.

```
tar cf - *.tex *.sty | docker run -i richardbronosky/latex-compiler > document.pdf
```

If multiple documents to be created, it returns a tar file that you can expand.

```
tar cf - *.tex *.sty | docker run -i richardbronosky/latex-compiler --tar | tar x
```

If you need more (or less) LaTeX packages, you can clone the repo and modify the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/RichardBronosky/resume/blob/master/latex-compiler/Dockerfile). Its current state is:

```
FROM ubuntu

MAINTAINER Bruno Bronosky <richard@bronosky.com>

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y texlive-latex-recommended

ADD latexcat /usr/local/bin/latexcat
RUN chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/latexcat

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/latexcat"]
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno , question was to minimize the download(s).Do you have any stats on how much space this setups requires including all the tools (e.g Docker) ?

Comment: Actually, that is not the OP's concern as he specifies "1,801 MB of disk-space". It's a valid question, and I don't know the answer. Because of the software development I do, I'm going to have Docker (which is rather small) anyway. I'm not worried about bandwidth. I'm worried about disk space and bloating my system with software I don't often need and which may cause conflicts with things I do use often. I'll see if I can get some numbers for you, but the size of Docker is going to depend on your host OS. It's much leaner on Linux.

Comment: I’m curious about which conflicts may be caused by a latex installation on an Ubuntu system..

Comment: @gigabytes Here is an example from one of my Ubuntu 14.04 systems. https://gist.github.com/RichardBronosky/75cea524cbb4d05ad36ac06d88b0cd16 Installing LaTeX would require 96 pages to be installed and 1 upgraded. Any of those packages could have different version requirements than what is on your system. In my specific case, libcups2 would get upgraded. Probably isn't a problem. But that's a LOT of changes to make to a system just to output a single document. Even if I used LaTeX daily, I'd do it with Docker.

Comment: Yes, If you consider upgrading one package a big change, I suppose that makes sense ;)

Comment: That’s not a “conflict”, btw. It’s a conflict with your administration policies, which arguably are not common for a end-user desktop machine, which is where latex is commonly used. On the contrary, such a machine should be always up to date anyway (using a stable system release of course). So while your specific motivations are clear I doubt it’s a good advice for everybody, especially if it involves learning docker etc..

Answer (score 5):

Depending on what packages your tex project uses, you can run `sudo apt install texlive-latex-base` or `sudo apt install texlive-latex-recommended`. The difference is that more libraries are included in the "recommended" version. Start with the base package which was 228 MB on my system (including dependencies). Then install the recommended version if you are missing packages -- pdflatex will tell you if you are missing packages. The recommended was 388 MB on my system. There also exists an "extra" version which I have never needed.

Edit:
The `sudo apt install texlive-latex-extra` installation was 576 MB on my system. And I have actually needed it once or twice.